Has anyone calculated musical patterns of the planetary cycles?
Using a modern, logarithmic form for our musical scales, include the major planets, plus Ceres. Pluto and Eris for a wide coverage of our solar system, or any others you wish. Use the NASA Planetary fact sheet for the data points and solar day length and tropical year length where available (ceres, Pluto and Eris don't have a known tropical year length as yet so you can use their sidereal year).
Using a mathematical computing software and logarithmic math makes this much easier.... in order to pull it off, you will have to reduce each comparative musical measurement between points to the ir primary intervals, which means you have to normalize all points of comparison to one octave length. To measure these interval each planet must be considered as a root note by which all other points are compared... you will have at least as many scales as planets you use. And if you use both day and year you actually have 2 scales per planet, because for the most part day and year lengths are not the same for any planet I know of in our system.
The musical scale of western classical and in much world music starts from a reference frequency, A4= 440 Hz. And it uses 12 notes and an octave length of 2.
So. our common harmonic system is
H(F)= F ×(2^(x/12)). Comparing each cycle to another in simple ratios, known as resonance ratios, you arrive at a musical interval. Reducing that interval to a number between 1 and 2 by either multiplying or dividing by 2 until you are there, or using the fractional part of the log 2 (f2/f1) will do the trick. Which planets, if any, have cycles that are within 1 percent of how we currently tune our instruments?

Sounds like a great project for you to pull up a spreadsheet and do!

Some scales are based on string length ratios, others on ratios of water volume inside resonant containers, yet others on size ratio of resonant surfaces. Those based on vocals are sometimes not limited to set patterns.

Have you tried googling the title of your question?  I have found that's often a very effective way of looking for a quick answer.  On the first page, I found this link which appears to answer  your question with "yes."  Of course, you will have to read the article to see whether its contents match the way you want to think about the problem. If it doesn't answer the question, can you edit the question to capture why that link doesn't fit?

The ratio of the lengths of Saturn and Jupiter's years once was is 2 to 1. This resonance had important consequences for the formation of the solar system. Earth probably wouldn't have life without it. See Why the Earth exists because of Saturn | Migration of Planets.
A number of objects, including Pluto, have a 3 : 2 resonance with Neptune. They are collectively call Plutinos. Other trans-Neptunian objects have various other resonances Resonant trans-Neptunian object.
3 moons of Jupiter have a 1 : 2 : 4 resonance. Orbital resonance
Planets around other stars often have resonances like this.

That info on saturn is great stuff, sir. Thank you. I have been pursuing this question for 4 years.  That is something I have not come across.
